# Why tag 'graalvm' not exist in superuser?

Tags: discussion

I have question regarding to install GraalVM but i could not find graalvm.

GraalVM includes a JDK based on the Java HotSpot VM.

source: https://www.graalvm.org/22.1/guides/

Comment: New tags must be purchased with the StackOverflow microcurrency, 'reputation'.  It costs 1500 reputation to purchase a tag.

Comment: Probably because there have been [very few](https://superuser.com/search?q=GraalVM) questions that require it and cannot make do with broader tags such as [tag:java] or more specific operating system tags. There are 3 actual question including your own, so there's not much demand for it.

Comment: @sgfit creating a tag requires only 300 rep https://superuser.com/help/privileges/create-tags . That said you should consider whether a tag is really necessary or useful before just creating tags for everything.

Comment: The reason it doesn’t exist is because it’s simply unnecessary. It also doesn’t exist because nobody has created it. You also don’t provide any reason it should exist.

Comment: It is good to know tag issue may be reputation cause. But GraalVm is just in town.
GraalVM is new technology release as Community Edition for an open-source license in 2019 by oracle corporation. GraalVM Native Image is officially supported by spring boot 3 java framework and other.

Comment: yeah its good thing that tag are under surveillance to prevent tag flooding. I just want to specify more clearly than using general tag. And i respect all the participant for their valuable feedback regarding tag.